# Adding data to a JTable column by column

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have three one dimensional arrays set up:

```
 String [] columnnames = {"Item", "Volume of Item (Cubic Feet)"};

 String [] livingroomitems = {"Articial Plant/Hall Tree", "Bar Portable", "Bench", "Bookcase", "Bookshelves", "Chair,Arm", "Chair,Occasional",
          "Chair,Overstuffed", "Chair,Recliner", "Chair, Rocker", "Chair, Straight", "Clock, Grandfather*", "Computer",
          "Desk, Winthrop", "Desk, Secretary", "Desk, Office", "Desk, Roll Top", "Entertainment Center", "Fireplace Equipment",
          "Futon, Single", "Futon, Double", "Futon, Queen", "Futon, King", "Lamp, Floor", "Magazine Rack", "Music Cabinet",
          "Ottoman", "Piano, Baby Grand*", "Piano, Parior Grand*", "Piano, Spinet", "Rugs, Large", "Rugs, Small", "Sofa, Large",
          "Sofa, Love Seat", "Sofa, Sectional", "Sofa, Hideabed", "Stereo Components", "Stereo Speakers", "Table, Coffee",
          "Table, End or Nest", "Table, Sofa", "TV Big Screen*", "TV Console", "TV Model", "TV Stand", "VCR", "Chandelier*"};

 int [] livingroomdata = {6, 15, 5, 20, 5, 10, 15, 25, 25, 25, 5, 20, 10, 20, 35, 30, 30, 30, 5, 40, 60, 65, 70, 3, 2, 10, 5, 70, 80, 60, 10,
        5, 50, 35, 30, 50, 10, 10, 10, 5, 10, 40, 20, 5, 3, 2, 10 };
```

I understand that normally, I would have to create a 2-D `Object` or `Vector` to add `livingroomitems` and `livingroomdata` side by side into a `JTable`. However, I would like to keep `livingroomdata` as an `int` so that I can manipulate the data later. Is there a possible way to 1-D arrays into a `JTable` column by column so I don't have to change my data types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to keep livingroomdata as an int so that I can manipulate the data later.

All manipulation of data should be done via the TableModel. You have methods like getValueAt() and setValueAt() to manipulated the data. Then when the data is changed the JTable will reflect the change immediately.

You should NEVER change the data in the Array. The TableModel will NOT be aware of the change the table will never display the changed data.

If you need to manipulate the data outside the scope of the JTable, that is you don't want the changes to be reflected in the table, then you should extend the DefaultTableModel and create a `getVolumeValues()` method that will return all the int values for the TableModel in an Array.

> Is there a possible way to 1-D arrays into a JTable column by column

All that being said you can initially populate the DefaultTableModel with data from arrays by using the `addColumn(...)` method. The data will be copied from the Array to the Vector used by the DefaultTableModel so you should never reference the Array data again (if your table is editable) as the data may have changed.

Comment: Should I add a TableModel listener?

Answer (score 2):

I see at least two ways to do this:

1. Create your own table model and override the respective methods (e.g. `getValueAt(row,col)` etc.)
2. Create a wrapper object that is backed by your array and handles exactly one index of it. Note that while this would work for readonly cells, editable cells would at least require some additional setup, if it works at all (I'm not sure whether the table would try to create a new instance in which case you'd determine the array index to handle).

Comment: Creating a model would be nice, but it seems really difficult.

Comment: @Buttchinbro it's actually not that difficult, just extend `AbstractTableModel` and implement/override the necessary methods (probably 5 short methods with a few lines at most: `getColumnClass(col)` , `getColumnCount()`, `getColumnName(col)`, `getRowCount()`, `getValueAt(row, col)`).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would HIGHLY recommend you follow the advice of the other answers, but it is possible to do what you're asking.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TableDataTest extends JDialog
{
    public TableDataTest()
    {
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        model.addColumn("test1");
        model.addColumn("test2");
        model.addRow(new String[]{"testrow", "testrow"});
        model.addRow(new String[]{"testrow2", "testrow2"});
        JTable myTable = new JTable(model);

        add(new JScrollPane(myTable));
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        JDialog dlg = new TableDataTest();
        dlg.setSize(100, 100);
        dlg.setModal(true);
        dlg.setVisible(true);
        dlg.dispose();
    }
}
```